# Unable to select check box from dropdown in webpage using Selenium with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Hi I am new to selenium via VBA, I am trying to select the dropdown and from the dropdown I need to select a option which is checkbox. Unfortunately I cannot share the link.

I have trie few codes but it does not work, below are the code I tried

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(),'GT - ALL')]").Click
```

Here is the web element

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="billerId"> Mid </label><br>
<select name="billerId" id="billerId" class="billerId form-control" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
<option value="7">(7) Pay</option>
<option value="11">(11)</option>
<option value="GT1">(1) GT - ALL</option>
<option value="GT7">(7) GT - S1- LB</option>
<option value="GT8">(8) GT - S2 - LB</option>
<option value="GT9">(9) GT - S3</option>
<option value="GT6">(6) GT Whistle</option>
<option value="GT4">(4) GT -LB</option>
<option value="1">(1) Main - PP (2)</option>
<option value="4">(4) MTEST</option>
<option value="2">(2) test</option>
<option value="12">(12) RR1</option>
<option value="10">(10) RR Data</option>
<option value="8">(8) RR 2Mid</option>
<option value="9">(9) RR 3</option>
<option value="6">(6) Silver New PP </option>
<option value="5">(5) SILVER </option>
<option value="3">(3) Strike</option>
</select>
<div class="ms-parent billerId form-control"><button type="button" class="ms-choice"><span class="placeholder">All</span><div class=""></div></button>
<div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: none;">
  <div class="ms-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitilize="off" spellcheck="false"></div>
  <ul style="max-height: 250px;">
    <li class="ms-select-all"><label><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectAllbillerId">[Select All]</label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="7"><span>(7) </span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="11"><span>(11) </span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="GT1"><span>(1) GT - ALL</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="GT7"><span>(7) GT - LB</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="GT8"><span>(8) GT - S2 - 02/11/17 LB</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="GT9"><span>(9) GT - S3</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="GT6"><span>(6) GT Whistle</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="GT4"><span>(4) GT -LB</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="1"><span>(1) Main - PP (2)</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="4"><span>(4) MTEST</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="2"><span>(2) test</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="12"><span>(12) RR1</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="10"><span>(10) RR Data</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="8"><span>(8) RR 2Mid</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="9"><span>(9) RR 3</span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="6"><span>(6) Silver New PP </span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="5"><span>(5) SILVER </span></label></li>
    <li class="" style="false"><label class=""><input type="checkbox" data-name="selectItembillerId" value="3"><span>(3) Strike</span></label></li>
    <li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">No matches found</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be two elements with that xpath when you use the * to identify the selector to target. Since this returns more than one element it is in a list and so you cannot call click on it.

In order for the click to work you need to only get the element you want to click. Not sure which one is the button but these are the explicit xpaths for both:

```
//option[contains(text(), 'GT - ALL')]
```

Or

```
//span[contains(text(), 'GT - ALL')]
```

Comment: I apologize for the delay !! The following code worked for me thank you !!! //span[contains(text(), 'GT - ALL')]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an attribute = value css selector which is faster than xpath. Note that text value appears to be: `(1) GT - ALL`

Your dropdown and checkboxes are distinct.

---

**input checkbox element** (indicated by `type` attribute with value `checkbox` and that is part of an `input` tag element)

For the checkbox you can use

```
bot.findElementByCss("input[type=checkbox][value='GT1']").click
```

You can likely shorten that to:

```
bot.findElementByCss("input[value='GT1']").click
```

---

**dropdown** (indicated by parent `select` tag and child `option` tag elements):

There is a non checkbox which you would use the following for:

```
bot.findElementByCss("option[value='GT1']").click
```

Or

```
bot.findElementByCss("option[value='GT1']").Selected = True
```

You can swop the GT1 for other values if required.

Comment: I apologize for the delay !! The following code worked for me thank you !!! bot.findElementByCss("option[value='GT1']").click

Comment: Only one can be accepted. When you have over 20 points (or something like that) you can upvote other answers you found helpful. The idea being you accept the answer you feel was the best for you and over time, hopefully, the rest of Stackoverflow votes and ensures the most useful answer rises to the top.